# Insert a break <br /> with mootools

Tags: javascript, mootools

I want to insert a break element `<br />` after a label `<label>` by using mootools. Unfortunatly this line of code don't work:

```
$$('.class-name label').inject('<br />', 'after');
```

Should I create the element `<br />` first with mootools? Thanks for reply.

Comment: When you say "don't work": Are you getting an error? Have you checked with your Chrome Dev tools to see if the element is being inserted but not rendered?

Comment: I get this error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of null"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is not a valid element constructor `"<br />"` and inject works reversed - `newel.inject(target, where)`. you want `grab`

```
$$(".class-name label").grab(new Element("br"), "after");
```

if performance matters (IE and many many items)...

```
(function() {
    var br = new Element("br"), after = "after", inject = function(el) {
        el.grab(br.clone(), after) // or br.clone().inject(el, after)
    }
    $$(".class-name label").each(inject)
}());
```

or even - to avoid the mootools el constructor penalty, I'd personally go with the following:

```
(function() {
    var br = "br",
        after = "after",
        doc = document,
        ce = 'createElement',
        inject = function(el) {
            el.grab(doc[ce](br), after)
        }

    document.getElements(".class-name label").each(inject)
}());
```

to be honest, you should solve this in CSS first if possible.

Comment: Thank you. The first example works for one label, the last one works even for more than one label.